# Why does no one stand up to protest the strike of Canadian federal officers who are earning about 45% more than average Canadian workers?

Tags: taxes, canada, freedom-of-speech

Considering the economic down-trend, most highly educated individuals struggle to find a job. The Canadian federal officiers have the above-average pay, **above-average benefits, above average stability, with below-average working hours** and intensity. Grown up in Canada, we recognize the profession of public servant as a first-class job, with household income close to the high middle class. Their strike, while benefiting themselves, disrupts normal public functions. They harmed the general public in this sense. For example, travel documents are delayed and family reunion is delayed or becomes more difficult.

For a quick Google search, multiple sources suggest that Canadian federal workers earn an average salary of $75,620 dollars per year (other sources say C$79,780), which is about 45% more than the Canadian average, and 85% percent more than the Canadian median. For reference:

> Alberta offered the highest average and median income of $56,100 and $42,500.
>
> The bottom 50% of Canadians earned a median annual income of only
> $17,800.

The last line is based on https://themeasureofaplan.com/high-income-canadians/ and is approximately similar to the data provided by [statistical Canada](https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2021/dp-pd/dv-vd/income-revenu/index-en.html).

Of course, they are free to feel unsatisfied with their job. However, we can image that most of those highly educated unemployed Canadians will be more than happy to have themselves placed into a position of federal worker. Furthermore, the fed workers are striking against us -- the common taxpayers -- not the capitalists.

So, my question is, provided that only 30% vote to support the strike of federal worker, why did none of the unemployed Canadians and common taxpayers 1. protest against the strike which disrupts public services, 2. offer themselves as replacement to those federal workers, 3. have a healthy degree of public media presence?

[image]

Canada public sector: The "median pay" data is hard to find so it is listed here only for reference. I am very open to more reliable data source. Hopefully it will include both the average data, median data, and the payroll data including benefits.

For now we have the following reliable sources, with limited data:

[Salary for entry-level jobs](https://%20tbs-sct.canada.ca/pubs_pol/hrpubs/coll_agre/rates-taux-eng.asp)

[Personnel Expenditure Analysis:](https://www.pbo-dpb.ca/en/publications/RP-2324-002-S--personnel-expenditure-analysis-update--examen-depenses-personnel-mise-jour#:%7E:text=Largely%20driven%20by%20one%2Dtime,%2460.7%20billion%20in%202021%2D22.) total personnel spending and its growth rate pre-strike.

---

Editorial note: tried to incorporate many sources and numbers from the comments. Tried to be as neutral as possible to *equally* include the evidences from both sides.

[image]

Comment: Google searches for average Canadian salary gives $59k and average federal worker salary at $45k so the opening premises seems flawed.

Comment: What, drag everybody's pay down because some people get less than they should? Sounds like a great way to keep everybody's income low. How does that benefit the people with low income again?

Comment: @Jontia You did you count the unemployed and self-employed

Comment: @dodo I didn't count anybody. I simply asked what the average salary was in the usual way. If you have a different number I suggest providing the source for people to judge the quality for themselves.

Comment: Glassdoor for example is self entered and unverified. It is unlikely to represent a real average as it will be skewed towards higher paid federal employees as those are the ones more likely to use the site.

Comment: The premise is flawed as @Jontia suggests.  Average government salary shouldn't be similar to overall average salary any more than average salary in any given industry should be.  Government jobs are not broadly representative of the labor market.  A fairer comparison would look at average salaries of nongovernment workers in similar jobs, and I imagine that would show a much closer comparison.  In some sectors, private employees probably make more (lawyers, for example).

Comment: Looking at the question, and particularly the edits made to the question, I've voted to close as an attempt to promote/discredit a particular cause.

Comment: People do realize that if salaries in general increase that they can get their salary increased as well. They also realize that if salaries in general decrease that their salary will decrease.

Comment: @JamesK This is because some comments and answers aim to promote a particular case, and I am citing facts to clarify

Comment: @JoeW Hi Joe, federal workers are paid by us: the commoners who pay sales taxes and income taxes. We are paying and they are striking against us. I think it makes more sense for a commoner to support a strike against a company.

Comment: @JamesK If you are referring to the link to PSAC case, I've removed the link to obey our forum rule. Note that only 30% of votes support the PSAC strike 2023: it is weird that all media contents, including the ones here, are supporting PSAC

Comment: I'm not referring to the link.  I'm referring to the tone of the question, which seems to me to be making the case for opposing this strike, and so the purpose of this post is to build support for this position, rather than ask a question.  In particular, the "side notes" are rebuttals, not clarifications.  If you are rebutting something, that means you are engaging in debate, not asking a question.

Comment: @JamesK Ok I removed the rebuttals. Good suggestions.

Comment: If you're comparing mean of one to median of the other, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @shoover Median data is not readily available but I offer a source

Comment: Federal workers also pay taxes and your taxes don’t pay federal workers but fund the government in general

Comment: @JoeW Fed use our taxes to pay the fed workers.

Comment: The latest updates appear to show an average salary, $75k below an entry salary of $87k. This is looking less and less credible.

Comment: And by that same logic federal employees also pay taxes and pay their own salary. Trying to claim otherwise makes it look like you are pushing an agenda.

Comment: @Jontia Welcome come to provide your credible source as I have a disclaimer that the data is hard to find. Unlike the union supporters, I am very open for discussion and consider the evidence from the both sides.

Comment: @JoeW I am not claiming anything other than listing facts. Seems like you are pursuing an agenda.

Comment: Well this is probably better. https://www.tbs-sct.canada.ca/pubs_pol/hrpubs/coll_agre/rates-taux-eng.asp I only read the CS and AS employees one. But it put entry levels at $56k for CS and $37k for PA. Well below you 'entry level' figure. And this is the Official government agreements.

Comment: @Jontia Ok I deleted my numbers and added your link to the body.

Comment: If you are just claiming the facts you would not have objected to the fact that federal employees are tax payers as well and they are also paying their own salary. Or the fact that tax payers are not actually paying anyone's salary and are just part of government funding which is what is actually paying people's salaries.

Comment: @JoeW Why did you put your words into my mouth? If you give me the exact numbers and percentage I won't deny it.

Comment: Shouldn't the people in charge of running a country (a difficult, complex job, that has important effects on real people) get paid more than average?

Comment: I am not unsympathetic to the question - government workers aren't typically the ones needing union protection all that much.  Workers in dangerous jobs?  Yes.  In typically abusive employer contexts, like farm workers?  Quite possibly.  Government?  Hah!.  But I have a real problem with the claimed pay rates for Federal workers.  And since your question is predicated largely on that...

Comment: I am just using your comment that people pay taxes and your response to my comment about federal workers also paying taxes that goes towards their salaries

Comment: @JoeW Tell me how much they paid, and how much others paid.

Comment: "bottom 50% of Canadians earned a median annual income" is a very strange way to say the 25th percentile...

Comment: @xngtng Most if not all of the words are just copied and pasted or paraphrased: trying hard to be not opinionated.

Comment: This isn't about how much person X paid versus person Y. Both of them are going to pay based on how much income they have with the person who has more income paying more. In the end the tax payers are not paying a federal employees salary, they are funding the government who turns around to pay the employees.

Comment: @JoeW You pay fed, fed pay officers

Comment: Correct, and that means you are not paying the workers and they are not paying themselves with their taxes.

Comment: @JoeW Fed use your money to pay the officers.

Comment: And that is the feds paying workers, not you. It really sounds like you got an agenda with this question with trying to insist that the median income is only 18k and that tax payers directly pay the wages of federal employee instead of just funding the government.

Comment: Here is a fact check on the claim of many Canadians making 18k a year. https://factcheck.afp.com/doc.afp.com.338N7F8

Comment: @JoeW@JoeW Statistical Canada says something like 22k and your AFP says 26k, still much lower than 70k. AFP and many "factcheck" organizations are also known to be biased. Check https://www.npr.org/2012/01/10/144974110/political-fact-checking-under-fire https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4592/63028. Why you are still pushing for my responses after I stop responding you under the answer?

Comment: @dodo the numbers you gave are still inaccurate and everything I have seen says it is much higher.

Comment: @JoeW What's your number and source? You are pushing hard to falsify my number, without providing yours exact numbers.

Comment: @dodo The fact check shows your initial numbers are wrong and google search shows the difference between the groups are much less. https://www.google.com/search?q=canada+average+income&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 "The average annual salary in Canada in 2021 was $59,300. That number if divided by 12 brings the average monthly salary to $4,942. Ranked among the top 20 countries with the highest salary, "

Comment: @JoeW 1. You AFP source says 26K, 2, You seems confuse "income" with "salary". 3. You seems confuse with "average salary" with "median income of the bottom 50%". That's two different economic definitions. Based on these, your comments seem to serve as tool to silence me rather than being constructive.

Comment: You are using numbers that are incorrect and trying to confuse people by making claims such as "median income of the bottom 50%" which I still say is trying to push an agenda

Comment: @JoeW You are still insisting that my data is incorrect despite that I provided a clear source: It seems like you are trying to shut me up.

Comment: @dodo I am saying that I am seeing inaccuracies with your data based on what I am getting from google and your attempts to compare different sets of data such as one groups average salary and a second group that cuts off at least 50% of the population and using median income for that second group. If you want to compare salaries you should be using the exact same filters and calculations on both sets of data.

Answer (score 8):

You are analysing this from the wrong perspective - The public are never happy with strikes that affect their daily life. But the public are also smart enough to recognize that a strike is a political protest, and thus are willing to tolerate the inconvenience of it if they support the politics behind it or trust the government to handle it democratically.

Let's assume you are right that the striking Canadian Federal Officers are earning more than 45% of the average Canadian workers. Then the first question that most of the remaining 55% Canadian workers will obviously have is why do those with stable jobs, earning so much, have to strike?

**Those striking have made clear demands**:

1. They want wage increases to keep pace with inflation.
2. Better job security (protections against layoff, permanent employ instead of short-term contract hiring etc).
3. Right to work remotely (from home or elsewhere).

**For any worker, private or government, in low-paying or high-paying jobs, all these demands are quite reasonable as all workers desire the same too.**

A wage increase that doesn't consider inflation can be practically meaningless as it won't improve your savings or quality of life. The increasing trend of hiring workers only on short-term contracts means both the government and private businesses can exploit workers by paying them lower wages - if anyone protests, they can be threatened that their contract won't be renewed. Those hired on contracts are also denied other benefits that regular workers are entitled to.

> Diana, a striker in Mississauga, explained the challenges posed by the rising cost of living, commenting, “I don’t go out for dinner at all. I don’t go to movies any more. I literally don’t do anything any more. All I do is work, pay my bills, walk my dog in the park. There you go.”
>
> ... Asked what she thought of the government’s claim that it cannot afford to grant public servants a wage increase that keeps pace with inflation in light of its funnelling $650 billion to the banks, businesses and wealthy investors with no strings attached at the onset of the pandemic, Olivia replied, “Don’t we also deserve something? We served through the pandemic. We’re essential services. Everything from cradle to the grave. We’re asking for a humble raise.”
>
> ... “One thing the public doesn’t know is that our contracts expire and it takes years for them to get renegotiated. So we’re not negotiating our contracts before they expire any more like we did when I started 15 years ago. Now it’s four years before we’re renegotiating. So you can imagine the next one will be two or three years from now. This one expired in 2021,” he said.

"Right to work remotely" is a post-covid phenomena that has become quite popular. During the pandemic most of the world workforce was forced to work from homes. Canadian government officials were no exception. Thus, these Federal workers now claim that they have proved that it is very much possible to do their jobs from their home too, and hence should be allowed to work remotely too. For their own reasons, the government bureaucrats and private corporations are strongly against encouraging remote work. But it is very clear, around the world, that this is a very popular demand.

> ... Workers explained how their demand for the right to work remotely would help them achieve a better balance between their professional and family lives. They also pointed to the financial benefits under conditions in which their pay checks are stretched. “Thankfully we don’t have to drive if we’re working remotely. Otherwise you add another $500 for your car and $300 for gas,” stated Olivia. “That’s $800 just for transportation every month.”

> ... While refusing to make any concessions on the issue of remote work, the Trudeau government is cynically encouraging government workers to scab on the strike by working from home. According to a report in the Globe and Mail, government officials emphasized in press briefings that workers can continue to receive full pay during the strike by logging on to their work accounts remotely.

The average Canadian worker is smart enough to understand that if the government accommodates these demands, even partly or fully, **it will have rippling effect in the private sector too**. They can also see that the biggest objections against the unions, and their demands, come from the richer corporates. Unlike the Americans, Canadians don't have any delusions that governments should always prioritise corporate interests.

**That brings us to the politics behind this strike.**

The Trudeau government wanted to lay off many government staff, and replace them with fewer temporary contract workers as part of its *austerity* measures. If a government is allowed to do this with impunity, without any resistance, government workers rightly fear that this will lead to an erosion of their hard won rights. There are also questions if firing government workers is the best way to save some money.

**Ordinary Canadian citizens thus recognise that the government is partly responsible for this mess** and have poorly handled this issue. Political protests (like a strike) happen when the government doesn't democratically engage with all the *stakeholders* properly when implementing a policy. If the government gets carte blanche to lay off government workers, and hire fewer contract workers to replace them, this can become an entrenched norm in the private sector too. **Which average Canadian worker will support less job security, more workload, less pay in their right mind?**

Thus, from the above political perspective, it is easier to answer your doubts:

> why did none of the unemployed Canadians and common taxpayers 1. protest against the strike which disrupts public services,

The citizens aren't against the strikes because they support the politics behind it and / or they don't like the current government's policy (i.e. they blame the government) or they trust the government to handle the issue, one way or the other.

> 2. offer themselves as replacement to those federal workers,

In general, the legal system of most democratic nations don't allow the government to easily fire striking workers as it violates labour rights. So even if other jobless citizens offer themselves as replacement (assuming they are qualified), Canadian law may not allow the Trudeau government to hire them. Doing so also will negatively impact Trudeau's poll prospect in the future.

> 3. have a healthy degree of public media presence?

Corporate backed media is already heavily critical of the strike and the unions. And it is in their interest to not give media presence to unemployed citizens as that can turn the political focus on unemployment. Then the debate may shift on to whether the current administration is favouring corporates.

**Source**: [Strike by over 100,000 Canadian federal government workers continues for third day](https://www.wsws.org/en/articles/2023/04/21/sqew-a21.html) (21 April 2023)

*(**Note**: I have deliberately chosen a "biased socialist" source that presents the striking workers side. If the Canadians are supporting, or not against, the strikers, it is obviously because they are swayed by their political arguments which only a "biased source" will detail)*.

Comment: Thanks for this good answer. Just one thing. It is possible that the corporate-backed media is against the unions in private firms. However, in this question, the union is protesting against the federation (which is every citizen), not against a private firm owner. So it makes sense if a corporate backed media is not criticizing this type of unions.

Comment: Also don’t forget that people simply fail to understand Econ 101. They forget that caving in to the demands benefits a small group of people while harming the economy overall - but the benefits are visible and concentrated while the harms are abstract and hard to measure.

Comment: @dodo Corporates are very much against all worker union. They fear that if any worker union succeeds in getting a good deal for its member (even if these are reasonable demands like minimum wages, overtime pay, paid leaves etc.), it can have a rippling political effect as other workers elsewhere may be inspired to form unions and assert their rights more aggressively more. (In fact, some point out the current strike was inspired by the partial success of last year's Ontario education workers strike in Canada). (1/2)

Comment: @dodo The deal “will have a ripple effect, quite frankly, for the rest of Canada,” said the Canadian Labour congress president, Bea Bruske. “All large private sector employers and all the other provincial and territorial governments” are going to take note of the details of the deal, Bruske said. - [May Day deal ends strike for 120,000 Canadian federal workers](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2023/may/01/canada-federal-workers-strike-deal) (2/2)

Comment: @sfxedit You made a point but let me clarify. Usually, the unions help the poor workers get minimal wage from the rich bosses. In this case, however, the specific union hep the rich men get more money from the tax payers who are poorer in average: sucking the poor to help the rich.

Comment: Hmmm, I upvoted this answer.  But I see several oversimplifications:  first, to tame inflation, you really can't index everyone's wages to it.  Second, while banks and corporations got plenty of $ from Covid funds, so did the average Canadian worker - they got less, way less, individually, but there are **lots** of workers.  #3 at some point, the CA government, if not under Trudeau, *will have to balance the budget*.  That may require having less government workers and that would not necessarily be a bad thing.  What's true is that the public doesn't perceive these demands as unreasonable.

Comment: Also, a cynic might note that the sectors picked for strike action were, perhaps not coincidentally, rather unlikely to provoke ire by the average Canadian [*citizen*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2023_Canadian_federal_worker_strike#Impacts_on_federal_programs,_services,_and_operations).

Comment: @dodo are you really calling workers who make $75,000 a year rich? That level of salary is no where near high enough to call them rich.

Comment: @JoeW Rich comparing to the majority Canadian who makes a median of 18K

Comment: @dodo I highly question that number and that still does not make them rich. It really sounds like you are pushing an agenda here. The number I see suggest 18k isn't anywhere near the real numbers. https://www.policyadvisor.com/magazine/what-is-the-average-income-in-canada-2023/#:~:text=According%20to%20Statistics%20Canada's,take-home%20pay%20is%20%245%2C700.

Comment: @JoeW Questioning one's good faith and motives is ad hominem. Anyways, according to you logics you are pushing the cause of the federal workers' union. The question is closed and I'll stop here.

Comment: @dodo making claims that people making 75k a year are rich and by using incorrect information about people only making 18k a year appears to be pushing an agenda. It seems to be shifting the focus from the people who are actually rich to average people who are trying to make a better living. Instead of focusing on the people who actually control the paychecks of the low income workers you are instead focusing on others. https://factcheck.afp.com/doc.afp.com.338N7F8

Comment: This is a great answer, but I'd also add with the point about offering themselves as replacements to those federal workers - if the unemployed do "[scab](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scab)" (By taking the positions another federal employee had when striking and taking their position away - see definition 3. b.).), they're not going to get better conditions than the striking workers - they're going to get worse conditions (i.e. Less stability, less benefits, less pay, etc.). And when things get too bad for them...

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica *they got less, way less, individually, but there are lots of workers.* - if they all totally got way, way, way less share than the corporates, that's kind of unfair isn't it?  As you said there's a hell a lot more of them, which means unless the pie is large, all of them get a smaller piece. [Where's C$27.4 billion, that was allotted to workers and small businesses](https://www.canada.ca/en/department-finance/news/2020/03/canadas-covid-19-economic-response-plan-support-for-canadians-and-businesses.html), compared to the C$500+ billion allotted for the corporates?

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica *at some point, the CA government, if not under Trudeau, will have to balance the budget.* Sure, that's a given. But is firing government workers really the best way to go about it? Do you think a government official who is fired, and unemployed, will be happy that the administration chose to [prioritise giving off C$8 billion to foreigners](https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/ukraines-zelenskiy-visits-close-ally-canada-after-challenges-us-trip-2023-09-22/) while claiming they needed to be fired because money is tight? It's going to be a hard sell ...

Comment: @sfxedit How about you not run our foreign policy for us, eh?  $8B is chump change wrt to the, longstanding, CA deficits.  It doesn't take a whole lot of economic literacy to understand that, if you support companies that are shut down due to covid, in order for them not to go bankrupt, it will show up as support for... drumroll... the companies, not directly to its workers.  So, if you want to complain about that, be my guest.  Like I said, some good points to this answer, but at the same point it goes some way to support the accepted answer's claim of lack of economic acumen by the public.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I am sure you as a Canadian are much better informed of politics in your country. I was just pointing out the incongruence in Trudeau's policies that invites valid criticism. And I don't believe Canadians are anywhere as naive as Americans to believe in "trickle down" policies. It's easy for us to do armchair politics when our job isn't at stake. And while we expect the public to be rational about foreign policy, a person deprived of his livelihood suddenly, and that too by their own govt. they look up to, to secure their basic needs, will be anything but rational.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica And an administration needs to be sensitive to the criticism from the opposition. That is why even Biden has been pragmatic in postponing aid for the Ukranian temporarily, in favour of prioritising domestic politics. For while the Republicans are definitely doing opportunistic politics on funds for Ukraine, there is one very valid point they are making, that many Americans also support - clarification on what is the end goal that Biden's administration seeks in the Russian-Ukraine conflict and how it benefits America.

Answer (score 3):

Frame Challenge: People normally don't protest when someone who makes more then them goes on strike.

You don't see protests over pro athletes going on strike asking for more money. You don't see protests over actors/writers going on strike asking for more money. You don't see protests over highly paid union workers going on strike asking for more money.

Just because they are striking doesn't mean that people will protest it even if they disagree with what is being asked for.

Answer (score -2):

When you say it "causes public harm", it doesn't cause harm to the working public, since the working public benefit from strikes and general increases in the market level of pay. So that assumption is flawed to begin with.

For other workers to attack the strike by attempting to break it has a name: scabbing. There's two reasons why workers may not do this.

Firstly, they may support the strike and support the challenging of employer power. Unemployment exists only because of state policy to attack workers, so the unemployed man does not necessarily align with the employers and against other workers, because he potentially recognises that he's being played as a pawn when urged to scab.

Indeed, the unemployed, having little or nothing to lose personally, may join in to promote mayhem against scabs - and the broader working community will approve.

Secondly, such scabbing often provokes an escalation in violence and retaliation, so that the scab risks being physically beaten and any of their property smashed, including potentially long after the strike. So even the scab not controlled by ideological sympathy, will be controlled by self-interest.

From the employer's point of view, firstly they risk having their machines and property smashed in an escalation to prevent scabbing, and despite hiring scab workers they risk not getting work done because of picket lines and other kinds of interruptions.

It's not always an option to simply send in police or army, since they are public workers whose own pay and conditions may be under attack by the employers, and they may either sympathise with the strikers anyway, or will come to sympathise through the process of confrontation.

Secondly for the employer, scab workers are often untrained and inefficient, they may risk damaging things or personal injury, and may have to be paid large premiums in wages (which is what the employer is trying to oppose for the strikers), so it isn't necessarily a better solution to keeping the operation going than just accepting the pay demands of the strikers.

There are also wider political effects from constantly attacking workers, that can take decades to mature, but is manifest currently by the sense that nothing seems to work anymore and the authorities are losing control of people in every respect.

Those are largely the circumstances in which the right to strike was won. Originally, strikes were always illegal, but what the authorities representing employers eventually found was that strikes occurred anyway, sympathies became widespread, and many lawmen sympathised with strikers.

Each atrocity the authorities committed to try and cow workers, was simply followed by more extreme violence and more destruction of employer property and public infrastructure, including continuing in disorganised and autonomous ways whenever labour leaders were eliminated, and the work still didn't get done on the terms the employers wanted it done.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Virginia_coal_wars

Comment: If you live in Canada, you will know, for general public, how difficult it  was to get things done during the strike.

Comment: You are giving too much negative connotations for federal workers who is scabbing. They are the ones keep the public system functioning during the strike: this is doing the public good, not the other way around.

Comment: @dodo, but no less difficult for the strikers I'll bet. The level of hardship is immaterial. People in WW2 put up with bombs through the ceiling. It's who is blamed for the hardship - if the public blame intransigent employers for causing the strike by attacking pay, then it's the employers who will bear all public ire.

Comment: The strikers are getting a salary 85% more than common Canadians. If they are "difficult" then the general public is starving. Also, making a comparison between our peace-time and WWII is a bit extreme.

Comment: @dodo, it depends whether certain workers are continuing to work with the permission of the strikers or not.

Comment: @dodo, that's like saying concentration camp inmates would naturally be against the allied soldiers who were reasonably fed. If the general public is starving, they may plausibly support those confronting the employers and fighting for more.

Comment: No true. Allied soldiers are fighting to free the prisoners, while the fed workers fight for themselves not the 50% majority Canadian who is earning C$18K per year. If more resources are going into the upper-middle class, less money is going to the majority low-class

Comment: @dodo, you could equally say most soldiers are fighting for themselves or their own families - with probably very little nexus to those in the camps. The vast majority of wealth doesn't go on wages at all, but on profits and rents, and those rents and profits can be cut back (or further taxed) to pay for increased wages. If the wages for the lowest paid could be any lower, they already would be - the bosses don't allocate any fixed amount to wages, they just pay as little as possible. There's no reason why an increase in wages for some, makes it possible to pay others less.

Comment: Ok, if I understand you correctly, are you suggesting a new political system in which the capitalism must be limited and the power of the ruling class and the bosses must be further limited?

Comment: @dodo, a system in which worker unions impose wage increases upon employers, certainly isn't "new".

Comment: Can you give sources that the Federal workers' union is requiring the government to increase rich-tax and the purpose of strike is that? If not, then your point is factually not true: they are not requiring rich-tax, but only requiring more pay.

Comment: You also mistakenly believe that federal workers are paid by bosses. They are actually paid by federal government, using mostly personal income tax, which could otherwise be used to feed the poorest.

Comment: @dodo, the poor wouldn't need to be fed if they were paid properly in work. People understand that the paymaster is the federal government, but it's the boss-interests who control politics who actually determine the behaviour of the federal government as an employer. Moreover, there is nothing to stop the government shifting taxation to the rich - current taxation may be personal, but it does not have to be. If the boss-interests controlling politics could increase taxes on workers, they already would have, and would have reduced taxes on the rich with the proceeds.

Comment: Moreover, they cannot explicitly reference these connections. They cannot warn workers "we'll put your taxes up if these unionised workers win", because that will just provoke the rhetorical question in response: why aren't the rich having only their taxes increased, to pay for better wages? They don't want to have the argument on those grounds, that there is some connection between who is taxed and what wages are paid.

Answer (score -7):

This answer constitutes no formal advice or opinion pieces. It does not focus on justifying a cause, but stick to answer the question.

I'd say more than 50% of individuals in my narrow circles are unhappy with the federal strike. Their feelings are like "Jes, the rulers are striking against we lower-class" (the logics are not necessarily factual). In fact, there are actually [30%](https://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/ottawa/uvae-picket-line-names-1.6842137) of federal workers who voted. However, they are not standing-up against the union due to the following three reasons:

1. For workers, [they don't want to be "hunted" by the union](https://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/ottawa/uvae-picket-line-names-1.6842137). Although going against the union is legal, few will do in public as the union is trying to everything they can to ["hunt" and punish people against them](https://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/ottawa/uvae-picket-line-names-1.6842137). If they fight, they will fight [anonymously](https://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/ottawa/uvae-picket-line-names-1.6842137).
2. For common taxpayers, their voice are suppressed because "going against the union" is politically incorrect for the mainstream media.
3. Comparing to the unions, the unhappy don't have an organization or a leader.

More reasons are also possible. I am open for more ideas.

---

Comments and Rebuttals:

We cannot deny that there are some people who is unsatisfied with the strike.

One answer mistakenly suggest that the strike will help the poorest by accelerating taxing the rich. In *fact*, increasing "rich-tax" is never an agenda of the union of federal workers. The union aims for [wage-increase only](https://www.reuters.com/world/americas/canada-public-workers-reach-contract-agreement-with-federal-govt-ending-strike-2023-05-01/#:%7E:text=May%201%20(Reuters)%20%2D%20Canada%27s,immigration%20for%20almost%20two%20weeks.).

That answer also mistakenly suggest that the "bosses" or the "capitalists" are paying the federal workers. In *fact*, they are paid with mostly personal income tax and sales taxes (>51%), which could otherwise be used to feed the poorest.

It is a common misconception that union is always against the "rich" or the "capitalist", making the discussion off-topic. While I think a union against the rich is fine, but a union against the common taxpayers like you and me is very different. Careful conceptualization and clarification is needed. It is the everyone who is paying the federal workers, not the capitalists.

Comment: Opinion based answers should be avoided

Comment: If the question and its comments didn't prove this is purely about pushing a position, this answer must seal the deal.

Comment: "More reasons are also possible. I am open for discussion." This is not a discussion forum, you should know this by now.

Comment: @Nij Which point I made in this answer is not fact or off-topic?

Comment: @Nij It is not about pushing an agenda, it is more about "on-topic". There are a lot of media articles claiming the benefits of strike, and this is not the focus of the question. The question is about: giving the fact that only 30% vote to support the strike, why did people was not supportive, why did they take no action, and why their voice is suppressed?

Comment: As I stated above, this is a rather good question (from both my experience living in France and Canada, where striking government workers are frequent).  But it would be hard to answer factually, unless subject-specific opinion polls were carried out.  But to ask such a question and to answer it with a rather "opinionated" answer within a few hours?  That looks less like question-asking and more opinion-pushing.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica The other answers are even more opinion-pushing. I am using facts to write a rebuttal.

Comment: I am not stating the other answers are less opinion-pushing. I DVed one of them as well.  **But they are also not coming from the person posting the question.**  The *" hunted by the union"* claim is also way over the top, without some serious referencing.  FWIW, I tend to be more anti than pro union.  And that esp. within a government employer context.  I just think it's quite dodgy to ask a Q and then answer it with one's own pet theory within a short time.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica The word "hunt" comes from one of the most influential and most serious media in Canada, CBC

Comment: I dunno about you, but I am well aware that criticizing strike-busters is a long union tradition.  No need for you to be all emotional about it, while I rather think our over-lefty taxpayer-funded CBC meant it as an expression of support for "hounding the faithless", rather than any notion of criticism towards the union.  Besides what the union does to its members to keep them in line has zilcho, nada, nothing to do with your question, **which is why the general public is not critical**.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I understand you point. But the closure of my question again proved the statement in my answer: the union and its supporter are doing everything to hunt-down the dissentient.